# I have this error while I am using http request?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

Hello I have this error after itemBuilder:(){
}
Here is the error

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type

Here is my code:

```
Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: HttpService().getBs(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Battles>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<Bs> s = snapshot.data!;
                    return ListView.separated(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        s.map((Bs b) {
                          {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                      itemCount: s.length,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ));
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add return

```dart
return  battles.map((Battles battle) {...
```

You dont have to use map here.

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List<Battles> battles = snapshot.data!;
  return ListView.separated(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10),
    itemCount: battles.length,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final battle = battles[index];
      return Container(
        width: 375,
        height: 375,
        child: ... // use this `battle` 
      );
    },
  );
} else {
```

[image]

More about [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

Comment: Hello, when I do that this error appear : The return type 'Iterable<Container>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Add a `,),` end of this snippet

Comment: still the same error

Comment: 1 question why you are mapping, are you trying to provide a list as single item

Comment: no, it's a listView.separated of dynamic items and  I am mapping because of http request

Comment: you dont need to map here. you can just get item  on `itemBuilder`

Comment: Thank you, its working, but I have another error while fetching data: error response Instance of 'StreamedResponse'.statusCode

Comment: Not sure about your current error, feel free  to create new question with providing necessary snippet

Comment: ListView is going to render list of battles, and itemBuilder can single widget at a item. As for the scenario we are feeding the list on listView `itemCount: battles.length` there for no need to create a map to get a single item. Also, `final battle = battles[index];` returns single item. If you wish to pass a list from itemBuilder you need to wrap item with column widget. like `retrun column(children:items.map((x)=>Text(x)).toList()`